# CoordinatorLayout and MapFragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm using `CoordinatorLayout` and `ViewPager` on my app to show tabs. One of the tabs has a `RecyclerView` and the other has a `MapFragment`. I had no problem implementing this except that the map seems to be off screen.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

and this is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_logo"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When you scroll up then you see the map and the button fine, but I want the map to fit the screen and how can I do that?

Comment: You will have to post your code as well, like Layout xml.

Comment: Please, **share** your xml file.

Comment: @Nawako Sorry, totally forgot that part :P here's the code

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CoordinatorLayout whit Linear or Relative Layout and see if this will fix your issue, I have notice that MapFragment in CoordinatorLayout will result in some strange shaking result when you move the map.